# jQuery: using a div embedded in a JavaScript variable as a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery custom scrollbar, and I invoke it like this:

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).on("load",function(){
            $(".main_text,#C2,.png_container").mCustomScrollbar();
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

That works correctly for all of the page elements except .png_container, but unlike the other sections, that section is only used in a JavaScript variable that is used to substitute text in a placeholder ID, and I think that's where the problem is.

Here is how it's called from an "onclick" button event:

```
<div class="main_text">
<div id="C2">Main Text</div>
</div>

if (type == 101) {
var X = "<header>First Section</header><br>A classic example of good form/<br><br>More information<ul type=\"circle\"><li>Element Point 1<br></li><li>Element Point 1</li></ul><i><span class=\"span_01\">So much better</i></span><br><br><div class=\"png_container\"><img class=\"png_format\" src=\"images/Element 001.png\"></div>"}

document.querySelector("#C2").innerHTML = X;}
```

The png_container has a separate set of scroll bars, but they are not replaced by the custom scroll bars (the other page sections do get the custom scroll bars).

Here is the relevant css:

```
.png_container{
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 800px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: green;
}

#C2{
    color:#DBDBDB;
     font-family: camphorW04-Thin,calibri,arial;
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-indent: 0px;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 250px;
}
```

So my question is:  how can I replace the scroll bars on a section that is embedded in a JavaScript variable, as shown above?

My research has found some similar questions, but none that answer this specific question, so I hope somebody knows the answer.  Thanks very much for any ideas.

Comment: Need to initialize the plugin on the png class every time you replace content of #C2

Comment: I initialize the plugin only once -- just below the opening <body> tag.

Comment: Fine but it won't work on elements that don't exist at that time.

Comment: _"I initialize the plugin only once"_ - and that's your problem.  The innerHTML of `"#C2"` doesn't exist in the DOM at the time you initialize, so the `.png_container` part of your selector doesn't find it at initialization time.

Comment: Add `$(".png_container").mCustomScrollbar();` after `document.querySelector("#C2").innerHTML = X;`.

Comment: The innerHTML shows up first here:  <div id="C2">Main Text</div>.  Do I initialize the plugin for C2 there?  I'm puzzled because the other elements exist right below the body tag only due to CSS, just like #C2.

Comment: Thank you, Louys Patrice.  It works with:      document.querySelector("#C2").innerHTML = X;
    $(".png_container").mCustomScrollbar();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the mCustomScrollbar plugin on load this way:

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
  $(".main_text,#C2,.png_container").mCustomScrollbar();
});
```

The two first selectors have matching elements at this moment. But there is no existing element to match the last selector since `.png_container` is appended on click.

So you can safely remove `.png_container` from the load handler...
And initialise mCustomScrollbar on `.png_container` when it exists.

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
  $(".main_text,#C2").mCustomScrollbar();  // Remove .png_container
});

$(".something").on("click",function(){
  if (type == 101) {
    var X = "<header>First Section</header><br>A classic example of good form/<br><br>More information<ul type=\"circle\"><li>Element Point 1<br></li><li>Element Point 1</li></ul><i><span class=\"span_01\">So much better</i></span><br><br><div class=\"png_container\"><img class=\"png_format\" src=\"images/Element 001.png\"></div>"}
    document.querySelector("#C2").innerHTML = X;
    $(".png_container").mCustomScrollbar();  // Add this.
  }
```